# Como resolver erro de cors no node

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, cors

Fiz meu backend com **node/express** normalmente e testei todas as rotas no insomnia e tudo ocorreu normalmente, no front(**vuejs**) fiz requisições via **axios**, todas as rotas tambem funcionaram, exceto a rota de autenticação de **token**, alguém sabe o porque?

Erro:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3333/api/v1/authorization. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed).
```

App do backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()


const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.routes');

app.use(cors('*'));

app.use(authRoutes);
```

Rota:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const verifyToken = require('../middlewares/token.middlewares');

router.get('/api/v1/authorization', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.status(100).json({
    sucess: true,
    message: 'Token is valid',
    decoded: req.decoded,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const headerAuth = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!headerAuth) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ sucess: false, message: 'No token provided' });
    }
    const [, token] = headerAuth.split(' ');
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          sucess: false,
          message: 'Failed to authenticate token',
        });
      }

      req.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ sucess: false, error: err });
  }
};

module.exports = verifyToken;
```

No frontend eu chamo ele assim:

```
import api from './api';
// api é um arquivo de configuração do axios, somente, e provavelmente está correto pois uso ele em outras rotas normalmente
async function authorization(token){
    const btoken = `Bearer ${token}`;
    api.get('/authorization', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: btoken
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    })
}

export default authorization;
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Vi que tá chamando `req.headers.authorization` e está setando `Autorization`, será se não é isso?  Case sensitive?

Comment: valeu pela ajuda, mas o erro nao tava ai, descobri que lá no middleware eu estava mandando o status 100 ao invés de 200, só precisei mudar e deu tudo certo

Comment: Legal... que bom que deu certo